# Exclusive Aspect Ratio Media Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to have a picture at the side of my site only if the browser width is >1200 px, but I want to use one of two pictures depending on the aspect ratio. I suppose I need to use

```
  @media all and (min-width: 1201px)  and (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5){
#div {background-image:url(pic1.jpg);}}
@media all and (max-width: 1201px)  and (max-aspect-ratio: 8/5){
#div {background-image:url(pic2.jpg);}}
```

However I worry that if the window is exactly 8:5, the user will have to download both images.

Any help on how to make sure only one image loads would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of testing, it turns out you don't need to change a thing:

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5) {...}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 8/5) {...}
```

I made a demo. Open it in full size and resize the browser. They'll never be both the same (true or false).

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.\31\30\30\25 {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
  justify-content: center;
}
.\35\30\25 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #fff;
  align-self: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  position: relative;
}
.\35\30\25:before, .\35\30\25:after  {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(25vw - 40px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: red;
}
.\35\30\25:before {
  right: calc(100% + 20px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  content: 'not above 8/5';
  text-align: right;
}

.\35\30\25:after {
  left: calc(100% + 20px);
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  content: 'not below 8/5'
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5){
  .\35\30\25:before {
    content: 'above 8/5';
    color: black;
  }  
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 8/5){
  .\35\30\25:after {
    content: 'below 8/5';
    color: black;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="100%">
  <div class="50%">
  </div>
</div>
```

While testing the above in full width and setting browser window to be exactly `800px x 500px` it says `not above 8/5` and `below 8/5`. I tested it in IE10, FF and Chrome.

However, if you want to make extra sure that only one applies, you don't have to rely on browsers. Even if both conditions are ever true, **if you modify the same property of the same element** for both media queries, only one will apply:

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5) {
    [same-selector] {
        [same-property]: [some-value];
    }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 8/5) {
    /* 
     * This one will apply if both media conditions are ever true.
     * If you want the other one, place that media query below this one.
     */
    [same-selector] {
        [same-property]: [different-value]; 

    }
}
```

If two rules apply on the same property of the same element, the one with the stronger selector applies or, if the selector is identical, the last one parsed by CSS applies. And there you have it! The last one you place in CSS, that's the one that applies when both conditions are true, if they ever are true simultaniously.

Comment: "While testing the above in full width and setting browser window to be exactly 800px x 500px it says not above 8/5 and below 8/5. I tested it in IE10, FF and Chrome." Make sure you're resizing the *viewport*, not the *browser window*. It is vanishingly unlikely that an 800x500 window will have an exactly 8:5 viewport unless the window and browser chromes happen to be the right size. Resizing the viewport to 800x500 shows "above 8/5" and "below 8/5" for me on every browser - as I would expect from any non-discrete media feature.

Comment: You might be right about that one, but by changing the same property of the same element one can be sure it's not possible to have two values at once, right? Unless it's Schrödinger's property, of course.

Comment: Absolutely - the problem arises only when you try to set different properties, for example setting width in one media block and height in another. An edge case for sure, but noteworthy in any case.