# Dealing with CSS background images on screens with different aspect ratios. (16:9 -> 9:16)

Tags: css, background-image, screen-orientation, aspect-ratio

I have webpage with a background image:

```
    body {
        background-image    : url("https://example.com/image.png");
        background-size     : cover;
        background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    }
```

This works fine for 16:9 screen but for a mobile phone(9:16), the image covers (kind of) only half the screen!

How to specify different images based on aspect ratio?

Comment: You can use media queries that target specific aspect ratios. Here is the first stackoverflow answer I found when googling "aspect ratio media queries" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381089/exclusive-aspect-ratio-media-query

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli that link helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This deals with aspect ratios in CSS :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio. Thanks @GabyakaG.Petrioli

```
/*background image to load for 9:16 display*/
    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 9/16) {
        body {
            background-image    : url("https://example.com/image1.png");
        }
    }

/*background image to load for 16:9 display*/
    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
        body {
            background-image    : url("https://example.com/image2.png");
        }
    }

/*Common properties can go here*/
    body {

        background-size     : cover;
        background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It may be problem with your image position

```css
body{
  background: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/nature-wallpapers-hd.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;
}
```

Show this, It may help you to understand `background-size`
[CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion/9264418)

Answer (score 0):

That will always happen as with `background-size: cover` the browser tries to fill the element with the same background. You can still do some adjustments with `background-position`, but it's not really helpful in these circumstances.

What could be much better is that you use media queries to use different backgrounds depending on the screen size.

Something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  background: url(../images/mobile-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  background: url(../images/large-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This way you can select specific images for both cases and some of the benefits include more adequate image size which leads to faster loads and less bandwidth consumption for the user. That also leads to better Page Speed results.